# Python Pandas sum() the difference between two values

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

In my python code, using pandas i have to resample a datetimedata series and calculate diffs between a column values (the sum of diffs between values), i write this piece of code:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime
from .models import Results, VarsResults

start_date = datetime.date(2021, 6, 21)
end_date = datetime.date(2021, 6, 24)

def calc_q(start_d, end_d):

    start_d = start_date
    end_d = end_date

    var_results = VarsResults.objects.filter(
        id_res__read_date__range=(start_d, end_d)
    ).select_related(
        "id_res"
    ).values(
        "id_res__read_date",
        "id_res__unit_id",
        "id_res__device_id",
        "id_res__proj_code",
        "var_val",
    )

    df = pd.DataFrame(list(var_results))

    df['id_res__read_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['id_res__read_date'])
    df = df.set_index('id_res__read_date')

    df_15 = df.resample('15min').sum()

    return df_15
```

but i get the sum of the values itself.

example

```
... | 5
... | 3
... | 1
```

i get 9
i would the sum of the difference between values not the sum of the values:

in this case 4 (5-3 = 2 + 3-1 = 2, 2+2)

Is there a method in pandas using resample for manage this kind of clcultion?

So many thanks in advance
Manuel

Answer (score 1):

The sum of all the differences is equal to the difference between the first element and the last one: if you work it out, all the other elements cancel out. In your data for example the 3 cancels out:

```
(5-3) + (3-1)
= 5 - 3 + 3 - 1  # - 3 and + 3 cancel out
= 5 - 1
```

I don't know how Pandas works, but you can simply do the equivalent of `first_value - last_value`.